# docx filetype upload issue with contactform7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 plugin in my website. In my Careers page I have a form to upload resumes and send as an attachment in email.

When I upload `.doc` file it is working fine, but when I try to upload `.docx` file console is showing errors like `err_connection_reset` and failed to load response from server something like that.

What is the workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add docx as an accepted filetype in the CF7 shortcode for your upload field, eg:

```
[file your-file filetypes:pdf|doc|docx|odf|rtf]
```